# Inserting selected data from table to another table

Tags: php, sql

I want to add the selected data from table1 to another table2
here's my supposed output.

Product Inventory List <-- displays the added product from 2nd table

Product List <-- this one display the products from 1st table

In "Product List"
I have my one listed product then if I click the "Add" Link, the data should be listed in the "Product Inventory List"

Anyway here's my code for displaying the data of 1st table

```
<?php 
$product_list = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productinformation1 ORDER BY date_added DESC");
$productCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($productCount>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row["ProductNo"];
        $product_name = $row["ProdName"];
        $product_list .= "Product ID:&nbsp;$id - $product_name &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &bull; <a href='#'>Edit</a><br>";
    }
}else{
    $product_list = "You have no products listed in your store yet.";
}

?>
```

And here's my code for displaying the data of 2nd table

```
<?php
$productsDB = "";
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productinformation");
$productDBcount=mysql_num_rows($sql1);
if($productDBcount>0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
        $id1 = $row["ProductNo"];
        $product_name = $row["ProdName"];
        $productsDB .= "Product ID:&nbsp;$id1 - $product_name &nbsp; &nbsp; &bull; <a href='product-add.php'> Add </a><br>";
        }
    }else{
    $productsDB = "You have no products listed in your store yet.";
}

?>
```

As you can see in displaying the data of 2nd table there's a link which is the "Add"
and now I want that link function as well..

And I don't know how get the data of 1st table and insert it in 2nd table so that it will this display in my "Product Inventory List"

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

your link should look like:

```
<a href='product-add.php?idtoadd=".$id1."'> Add </a>
```

and in product-add.php you will be able to do:

```
$sql = "insert ignore into productinformation1 (ProductNo, ProdName)
select ProductNo, ProdName from productinformation
where ProductNo = " . intval($_GET['idtoadd'], 10);
```

NOTE1: do not use mysql_### functions, use PDO or mysqli

NOTE2: do not use single quotes in HTML attributes, use double quotes

Comment: nothing happened in productinformation1 :(

I put the code 

<?php
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO productinformation1 (ProductNo, ProdName) SELECT (ProductNo, ProdName) FROM productinformation WHERE ProductNo = " . intval($_GET['idtoadd'], 10);
header("location: product-list.php");
exit();
?>

in product-add.php @llya

Comment: @JoemarAlfeche if nothing happend - then some error occurred, did you executed sql stored in variable?

Comment: @llyaBursov yes sir. the value from table 1 which is the productinformation is displayed already, but when I click the add the certain data of it didn't stored in table 2 which is the productinformation1.

Comment: @JoemarAlfeche how do you check for errors during sql execution?

Comment: @llyaBursov you mean using of Error Handling?

Comment: @JoemarAlfeche i mean you should use at least `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to check whether query is executed successfully

Comment: @llyaBursov sir if I click the "Add" link, nothing's happen its just like I clicked an ordinary link without function... I use the 'die(mysql_error())' but it won't display the error or something.

Comment: @JoemarAlfeche it is impossible, I suppose you already enabled error output in php.ini, and know the basics of php debugging?

Comment: @llyaBursov yes I did sir.

Comment: <?php
$sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO productinformation1 (ProductNo, ProdName, Category, SubCateg, Price, ProdDesc, date_added) SELECT ProductNo,ProdName,Category,SubCateg,Price,ProdDesc,date_added FROM productinformation WHERE ProductNo = ' . intval($_GET['idtoadd'], 10) or die(mysql_error());
header("location: product-list.php");
exit();
?>

Comment: @JoemarAlfeche where is connection to mysql is established? where is sql stored in variable executed vie mysql_query as I wrote before? Why are you lying?

Comment: @llyaBursov the connection to the database sir?.. or this <?php

$sql = "insert ignore into productinformation1 (ProductNo, ProdName)
select ProductNo, ProdName from productinformation
where ProductNo = " . intval($_GET['idtoadd'], 10) or die (mysql_error());

header("location: product-list.php");
exit();
?>

Comment: I was just coded the code that you've send to me sir. I'm not lying.

Comment: @JoemarAlfeche I gave you direction to use, I didn't provide you with copy-pastable solution, in your product-add.php you need to add code which establish connection and finally executes query